# How to deploy ERC-20 token on Aurora and bridge it to Ethereum Mainnet?

Tags: erc-20, evm, bridge

Can I deploy ERC-20 token on Aurora and bridge it to ETH Mainnet ERC-20 contract? We plan to launch our token as Aurora native ERC-20, but we’ll need to bridge it to Ethereum and NEAR Protocol. Would it be possible to include the token in the list of supported Rainbow Bridge tokens? What are the steps on how to do this properly via the Rainbow Bridge?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment bridging of Aurora native tokens to Ethereum is not possible, but eventually this functionality is to be added.

However, being ERC-20, the token should originate from Ethereum and then be represented on Aurora. To add it to Aurora, you’ll need to deploy it and create a PR in https://github.com/aurora-is-near/bridge-assets.

Comment: I have already deployed a token on Ethereum and want to use it as a DAO token on Aurora. How does Aurora bridge tokens - does it deploy its own standard tokens on Aurora at bridging request or does it allow custom tokens contracts deployed on Aurora to be bridged to Ethereum?

Comment: In this case, there’s no need to deploy a new token. You should just bridge the existing tokens to Aurora and use it as you want on Aurora.